# Laravel transitive relation fails

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I have an app with following models and relations:

`Contact` morphs many `Values`:

```
public function customFieldValues()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Value::class, 'model');
}
```

`Value` belongs to `CustomField`:

```
public function customField(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CustomField::class);
}
```

`CustomField` belongs to `Validation`:

```
public function validation(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Validation::class);
}
```

I wanted to add a shorthand for value validation, so I added the following to `Value` class:

```
public function validation(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->customField->validation();
}
```

---

The issue I'm having is when I try to eager load values with validation on a `Contact` model.

Doing `Contact::with('customFieldValues.validation')->first()` fails:

> Call to a member function `validation()` on `null`

(the `null` here refers to `$this->customField` in `Value` class `validation()` method)

When using the "full" relation without the shorthand, it returns correctly. So `Contact::with('customFieldValues.customField.validation')->first()` works.

Also when going from perspective of `Value`, it works fine: `Value::first()->validation`.

I used this type of relations before, does it have something to do with polymorphic relations? Can I make this work or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

It should works with this :

```
public function validation(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->getAttribute('customField')->validation();
}
```